# Java Android Plugin Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, plugins

I tried to add android plugin to eclipse but now eclipse is not working anymore - it is giving me an exception:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.100.v20110815-1419 [290]" could not be resolved. 
Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse; bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

Can  any one help me to find out how can I make it work because its not even starting.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eclipse -clean`. If that doesn't work, try moving your `.eclipse` folder somewhere else.

Comment: I am not able to open eclipse can u tell me how to do eclipse -clean?

Comment: I mentioned in the ans as wasnt able to paste whole exception please Check and help me.  Thanks in Advance @Robin